# Failed to start ADB server

Tags: windows, adb, daemon

I've been using adb earlier, and everything was ok. But since then some time has passed, and my system met with some changes, some services been switched off for example. Now I need to use adb again, but everything I got when I try to start the server is that error message:

```
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
could not read ok from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

I've searched for some time, tried every variants I found:

Antivirus/Firewall switched off completely

```
adb kill-server : cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037

taskkill /F /IM adb.exe : there were no processes to kill

netstat -ano | findstr 5037 : empty

net stop winnat : NAT service is not started (starting it doesn't help as well)
```

Hyper-V services are off also

My other computers start adb just fine, as this one (my main) did earlier, even with AV/Firewall on and without any additional efforts.
I guess it could be caused by absence of some disabled service which is needed by adb daemon. Could anyone help me to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you can run adb from any folder. Run console (cmd.exe) and print adb
If adb.exe not found you should check %PATH% env var, include platform-tools folder.